# What can cause poor quality video in Canon point&shoot camera?

Tags: video, camera, video-quality

I recorded some videos from my superzoom compact camera Canon Powershot SX150 IS. When I run these videos on camera itself, they run fine. But when I move them on PC and run it, I can see it being pixelate and gray framing many times.

I have tried it with Auto mode as well as M mode (where I can do all settings myself).

Am I missing some setting?
Or if I can repair these videos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On camera viewing is limited by the low resolution of the lcd-display of the camera. Maybe there is the same issues but you just don't notice them on the small display?

As for what might be causing this, without seeing a sample video, I'd suggest a slow memory card. Would you get these quality issues if you shot a video with one step lower quality? I would buy/borrow a faster or at least better quality memory card and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: I also suspect something may be wrong with the PC itself (namely the USB ports). articlestack, I suggest plugging the camera into an entirely different computer, transferring the files onto the PC, and seeing if you get the same problems. Sometimes, bad USB ports/busses can cause corruption during transfer.

Comment: Well I face that issue with all PCs. But memory card may be an issue. I dint try again however.

Answer (score 2):

Are you dragging the videos and watching them in an editing program such as Final Cut or Premiere Pro? If so, it is probably because you need to log and capture and run them through 'Compressor' to convert the files to a suitable format (say ProRes(LT)..)... I am guessing you are just viewing them in a default viewer, which in that case, as mentioned above it may be due to expectation from watching them on a smaller, lower resolution lcd screen on the camera..Though, the camera you mentioned should output fairly decent video... Hope this helps.

Comment: Camera video is usually either MJPEG or h.264.  Transcoding that to a different lossy format isn't going to help unless the player is choking on something in the camera file.  I'd expect that either you couldn't play it at all, or it would look fine, not that you could play but with quality problems.